# How Can I Make a Function That Returns a Value From a Coroutine?

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

I want to write a function that will always be called on the UI/main thread. Within that function, it will fetch text on a background thread (needs to access something from a file on the device) and then return that text to the main thread. Can this be done using coroutines in an idiomatic way?

Here is what I have done so far, but I fear it will run on the main thread:

```kotlin
fun getDisplayableName(context: Context): String = 
    if(someCondition)
        context.getString(R.string.someString)
    else runBlocking{
        var name String: String? = null
        launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            name = // some background logic, where name may still be null
        }
        name ?: ""
    }
```

I want to use this function in an Android activity:

```
@Override
fun onCreate() {
    // Other logic
    nameTextView.text = MyHelperClass.getDisplayableName(this)
}
```

I'm looking for similar behavior to handling asynchronous threading with callbacks, but obviously without the callbacks part.

For the sake of discussion, assume I can't use LiveData or ViewModels.

Comment: combine it with live data so you can observe the changes without including callbacks

Comment: Let's assume that I can't use LiveData or ViewModels.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `suspend` function

```
suspend fun getDisplayableName(context: Context): String =
    if(someCondition) {
        context.getString(R.string.someString)
    } else {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val name = // some background logic, where name may still be null
            name.orEmpty()
        }
    }
}
```

You would call it like this from `onCreate`

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    val name = getDisplayableName(this)
}
```

Comment: Thanks much for the input. But why does it not work if I simply pass the scope as a parameter into the function? Can it not be done that way as well? Or is the `suspend` modifier the only way?

Comment: In your code you are using `runBlocking`, that effectively blocks the UI thread until the operation completes. You must use a `suspend` function if you want to have the code run in the backgrond, using coroutines.